# Cannot construct an std::map with a customer compare functor?

Tags: c++, g++, stdmap

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class C {
public:
    C(map<int,int> m) { }
    int operator()(int a, int b) {
        return a < b;
    }
};

int main() {    
    map<int, int> m;
    map<int, int, C> mymap(C(m));
    mymap.insert(pair<int,int>(1,1));
}
```

Why do I get the following error?:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:16:11: error: request for member 'insert' in 'mymap', which is of non-class type 'std::map<int, int, C>(C)'
 mymap.insert(pair<int,int>(1,1));
```

Here is the coliru link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0413a35d3177ef48

Comment: This is the second MVP question in 1 hour

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What is MVP?

Comment: @NeilKirk: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a vexing parse - function declaration, where you'd expect an object.

Try this:

```
map<int, int, C> mymap((C(m)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
map<int, int, C> mymap(C(m));
```

In this mymap is taken as a function. Change it to

```
map<int, int, C> mymap((C(m)));
```

Comment: But m is an object here, not a type. Why is it not apparent to the compiler?

Comment: You can google "Most vexing parse" in C++. There are tremendous articles.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can also avoid vexing parse by using brace initializer:

```
map<int, int, C> mymap(C{m});
```

(Though if would behave differently if `C` had a constructor `C(std::initializer_list<T>)` where `map<int, int>` would be implicitly convertible to `T`, so that constructor would be called instead)

Update: as Benjamin Bannier pointed out, you can use brace initializers everywhere:

```
map<int, int, C> mymap{C{m}};
```

or

```
map<int, int, C> mymap{C(m)};
```

With the same precaution: `C` shouldn't have `operator std::pair<const int, int>()`.

Comment: Why only use that in the construction of a `C`, but not the map?